# Schedule downloads in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download, google-chrome-extensions

I need to download some large files for a game update through chrome.

However I get reduced speeds during the day. Is there a way in Chrome/extension that I can schedule the download to run eg 2am?

Answer (score 0):

This might not exactly answer your question, but on Unix-like systems, you can use `at`:

```
echo 'wget https://somedomain.com/largefile' | at 02:00
```